# FCM sometimes not receive push notification and sometimes receive push notification on android

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-7.0-nougat

I have a problem on FCM Android. The push notification is not received sometimes. I already put the code like in Google's tutorial but my apps are not working.

I already put this on **manifest** file

```
    <service
        android:name=".fcm.MyFcmListenerService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

and then added this

```
    <service
        android:name=".fcm.MyInstanceIDListenerService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

Comment: Mention Your Test Devices

Comment: @RAJESHKUMARARUMUGAM samsung OS 7.0, LG G5 OS 7.0 and emulator pixel OS 7.0

Comment: Can you find some pattern when you don't receive push? Like app foreground or background? Also what are you sending as payload?

Comment: I think you were wrong at some point when setup on the FireBase console. Please try app other.

Comment: @EduardoHerzer if never using apps and already in background. i just sending message

Comment: @quangminhs can you show me the setup on Firebase console

Comment: @Fajar let me try to understand: When app is in background you get notification. When app in foreground you don't receive the notification?

Comment: @EduardoHerzer oh sorry i means, when app never using until one hours or more and already in background the push notification from FCM not receive and when apps open or using the push notification receive.

Comment: same problem I am facing. If I removed my application from stack, application not able to receive push notifications and this is not specific for any O.S, this problem is for specific phones like Mi, Lenovo, Oppo etc.